# Sublime Text 2 python SublimeREPL

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimerepl

I am trying to add the packages install in sublime text. I have tried the following below:

To install it you need package control this lets you easily install plugins. To get it go here
 (http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control/installation) ,
 and follow the instructions. Once thats done:

1. in Sublime press Ctrl+Shift+P (linux command in ST for 'goto anything')
2. Type in 'install',**
3. click on 'sublime package control: install package'.
4. Then select SublimeREPL. It will install it automatically.
5. To use it go to Tools>sublimerepl>python from the menus.

I see the package control in installed packages, but I am at the following step 4  and I get nothing in the go to menu.

Anyone had this problem, and yes I have tried to restart sublime text

I am at the follwoing step 4  and I get nothing in the go to menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>** is the keyboard shortcut for the Command Palette, which is what you want. You can also open it via `Tools -> Command Palette...`. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> is Goto Anything, and has nothing to do with Package Control or installing things. Don't use it.

Open the Command Palette by whichever way suits you best, menu or keyboard shortcut. Once there, type <kbd>P</kbd><kbd>C</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> and ***Package Control: Install*** will be highlighted. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and a dropdown of the full list of available packages should appear. Now, type "sublimerepl" and it should show up. Click on it or hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and you should see a message at the bottom of the window that SublimeREPL is installing. Once it's done, restart ST2 (for good luck) and it should be available in the `Tools` menu down at the bottom.

Please read the [full documentation](http://sublimerepl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to familiarize yourself with this very powerful tool. If your desired Python binary is in a non-standard location, or you wish to use Python 3 or IPython, some additional configuration will likely be required.

Comment: Umm.. no sublimerepl did not show up for me. Yes I do have Package Control.